# htaccess rewrite if user requests for top level domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have following rule:
- If user is Yandexbot or bingbot, give 403 error for all pages except `index.html`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} YandexBot|bingbot [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.html) [NC]
#  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html? [L]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But I found out that this rule prevents these bots to access `http://example.com`. When bot requests these URLs I will serve "index.html" without 301.

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/
http://example.com/index.html
```

But I want these bots to not to access these URLs. I mean there won't be any characters after domain name:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?aaa
ttp://mywebsite.com/abcd
http://mywebsite.com/1234some
```

How would be the htaccess file ?

Comment: Hm, so it can access anything but `.+` rather then `.*`? (And check for an empty `QUERY_STRING` in your `RewriteCond`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} YandexBot|bingbot [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\ /+index\.html(\ |$)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

So:

- anything that has "YandexBot" or "bingbot" in the user agent
- if the request isn't for `/index.html`
- if the request is anything more than just a `/`